# Android: Send user location to the server every 15 minutes only if the location has been changed?

Tags: android, location

My app provides users location relevant notifications which means I need to be aware of my users' locations as real time as possible and not putting too much stress on battery.I have researched a bit and create the following list of option

- `partial Wakelock`: which lets the screen to timeout but CPU keeps executing task. But I just want my background code to be invoked every n seconds,check for location update,if the location is changed then send it to server.
- `AlarmManager`: I can use this to design recurring tasks but not sure if this will keep running in background indefinitely and can it be killed by users deliberately.

I want my background code to be invoked every n seconds as long as the app is installed on user's phone. I am looking for theoretical answers not the actual code as I need to understand what I am doing.

Comment: What's your specific problem?

Comment: I want to send my users location relevant information 24x7

Comment: Well, i am using Little fluffy library for doing so. There is no need to reinvent the well - https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use **Service** class as follows ,

```
public class StartService extends Service {

Timer timer = new Timer();
private final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;
GPSTracker GPSTracker;
Double latitude  ;
Double longitude ;



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    GPSTracker = new GPSTracker(StartService.this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doTimerThings();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void doTimerThings() 
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void run() {



            latitude = GPSTracker.getLatitude();
            longitude = GPSTracker.getLongitude();

            // you get the lat and lng , do your server stuff here-----

            System.out.println("lat------ "+latitude);
            System.out.println("lng-------- "+longitude);
        }

    }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);

}




@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```